# How to open python-3.bin file and install

Tags: python-3.x, interpreter

I navigated to the official python.org website and downloaded the latest Python interpreter which was 3.10.2. The package downloaded was named python-3.bin. How can I install it? Can't seem to find any .exe. Please help.

Comment: [Download from here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/python-3.10.6-amd64.exe)

Comment: Can you reconstruct how exactly you found that file on the Python website?  I have no idea what it is (and cannot find it myself), but if it being mislabeled such that people mistakenly think it's a Python installer, that's a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: The latest version of Python is 3.10.6. You were not on the official Python website - https://www.python.org

Answer (score 0):

A number of comments have already pointed this out, but it seems that you did not go to the official python website.

This is the website:   https://www.python.org/